# Can i change a react-native Project from expo-cli to react-native-cli?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I want to change my react native project from expo-cli to react-native cli. is it possible if yes, how can i change it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, it is called ejecting. Have a look at the [official docs](https://docs.expo.dev/expokit/eject/)